# Fetching and hashing a file from a URL in a Zapier code action in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, fetch, sha256, zapier

I was looking for a way to hash files manipulated in a Zapier code action and since Zapier does not provide such crypto transforms by default, I went on to implement it in Javascript.

The code below does this:

1. fetch the file from a public URL
2. hash said file using sha256
3. return the hash in the output

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');
    
return fetch(inputData.fileUrl)
  .then((res)=>{
    console.log(res.ok);
    console.log(res.status);
    console.log(res.statusText);
    return res.buffer()
  })
  .then((buffer)=>{
    const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
    hash.update(buffer);
    callback (null, {"hashValue":hash.digest('hex')});
  })
  .catch(callback)
```

I am basically calling 'fetch' on the S3 URL, returning the result as a buffer() call on the response object. I then create a 'crypto' object from said buffer, from which I create a sha256 hash and hex digest.

Note: 
Javascript code actions in Zapier can only take strings as input parameters, so any files you want to hash need to transit through a storage space (e.g. AWS S3 bucket) that has a **publicly accessible** URL. If you manipulate private/sensitive data, you may want to delete the file in a subsequent action in your zap. Beware also of non ascii characters in the URL (e.g. fetching from AWS S3 returns a 403 Forbidden error if your URL includes such characters as '€')

I hope Zapier users will find this useful, e.g. to automate workflows where you need to ensure file data integrity (accounting, invoicing ...)

Comment: Maybe you need to use Base64 before converting sha256

Comment: *not correct compared to any online hash calculator* which ones? What are you getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I edited my questions following further tests. Problem seems not to be crypto but the fetch from S3

Comment: hi! There's nothing magic about zapier's code step. does your code work locally? `fetch` is `node-fetch` on npm

Comment: hi again folks ... I have sorted my mess. It was a stupid mistake I overlooked in the file naming in my S3 bucket that included a euro sign (€). a browser can deal with this, but not node-fetch. oops. The rest works like a charm. I will edit my post so that readers have a reference for a handy hashing tool for their zapier code actions in javascript